# Can the intermediate Chern classes be expressed as Euler classes?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes, classifying-spaces

General question: We know that the top Chern class $c_n(\xi)$ of an $n$-dimensional complex vector bundle $\xi$ is its Euler class, while the first Chern class, $c_1(\xi)$, is the Euler class of its determinant bundle. Can the intermediate classes also be expressed as Euler classes of bundles related to $\xi$?

Let me also ask a much more specific question: We know that $H^\ast(BU(3);{\mathbb Z}) = {\mathbb Z}[c_1, c_2, c_3]$. Is there a complex 2-plane bundle over the classifying space $BU(3)$ (or $BU(n)$ for $n\geq 3$) whose Euler class is $c_2$?

Motivation: Long story short, I'm trying to construct an analogue of $c_2$ in a context where I know that the usual constructions I'm familiar with won't work. But I do have Euler classes in this context, so if I could express $c_2$ as an Euler class as above, I might be able to use that in my context. On the other hand, if anyone has a proof that there is no such bundle over $BU(3)$, then that will save me time chasing down that particular rabbit hole.

Comment: In Milnor and Stashev's "Characteristic Classes" (pg. 158 for me), they define all the Chern classes via the Euler class. Maybe this is not surprising since the kth Chern class of the tautological bundle over $BU(n)$ pulls back to the Euler class of $BU(k)$ for $k<n$.

Comment: That's one of the constructions I'm familiar with, but note that only the top class is defined directly as an Euler class of a bundle on the given space. The construction carries over to my context, but gives the "wrong" classes for reasons too complicated to explain in this comment.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, reduced mod 2 we have $Sq^2 c_2 = c_1 c_2 + c_3$ so the answer to the specific question is no.

Comment: @GustavoGranja: I believe you're right about the formula, but perhaps I'm blanking on something obvious: How does this show that such a bundle doesn't exist? If there were such a bundle $\xi$, it need not be true that $c_3(\xi)$ maps to the element $c_3$ in the cohomology of $BU(3)$.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question. Such a bundle would be classified by a map to $BU(2)$ which would pullback $c_2 \in H^2(BU(2))$ to $c_2 \in H^2(BU(3))$. That is precluded by the formula for the action of $Sq^2$ on $H^*BSU(3)$.

Comment: @GustavoGranja: Agreed about $c_2$, but we know little about what the map would do to $c_1$. So I'm still not seeing how the formula precludes such a map.

Comment: The image of the map on cohomology would be contained in the algebra generated by $c_1,c_2$ but this is not closed under the action of the Steenrod squares.

Comment: @GustavoGranja: Again, we know little about what the map would do to $c_1$ in $H^\ast(BU(2))$: There's no reason to expect it maps to $c_1$ in $H^\ast(BU(3))$. So I don't see that the image need be contained in that subalgebra.

Comment: It will map $c_1$ to some multiple of $c_1$.

Comment: @GustavoGranja: Yes, of course, now I see. If you want to submit your comment as an answer I'll accept it. Many thanks.

Comment: Are you ok with virtual bundles in your generalized setup?

Comment: @JohnGreenwood: Maybe. What do you have in mind?

Comment: @SteveCostenoble I thought there might a virtual bundle operation (a la Adams operations, etc) generalizing the "top exterior power" and "identity" operations that gives you the first and last chern class, but i tried a few things and nothing worked...it seems there's something special about the first and last symmetric polynomials!

Comment: @JohnGreenwood: Thanks for looking at it, anyway. With the search for such a bundle quashed, I think I've found a different approach to construct the elements I need. So it's all good in the end.

Comment: @SteveCostenoble Glad to hear it!

Comment: @johngreenwood Indeed, I have thought this for quite a while too. For instance the first and last symmetric polynomial define the trace and norm (in finite ring maps) and are additive and multiplicative and very important. But the other symm polynomials don't give any algebraic compatibilities as far as I can tell. Curious!